# How can I implement a form (login) that is visible on every page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

**Suppose I want my `_Layout` to include a login form instead of the default separate login view. How should I do this?** Searching around has given me very vague/uncertain answers.

```
 ___________________________________
|  _______________________________  |
| |  Logo                  _____  | |
| |                       |     | | |
| |                       |Login| | |
| |                       |_____| | |
| |_______________________________| |
|                                   |
|  Content                          |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|              Footer               |
|___________________________________|
```

Currently I have created a `LoginController` and corresponding `LoginViewModel` to handle the given username/password combo. Then the form `POSTS` to `LoginController/Index`. This solution is riddled with problems. For example, how do I provide the correct model to the `_Layout`? How do I perform validation? What about handling `ReturnUrl`?

Creating an abstract class for every other single model to inherit from, then giving it to `_Layout`, seems ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution:

The form itself submits to a designated controller/action:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account")
    ...
End Using
```

The controller has only the HTTPPOST action:

```vb
Public Class AccountController
    ' POST: /Account/Login
    <HttpPost>
    Function Login(ByVal viewModel as LoginViewModel) As ActionResult
        WebSecurity.Login(viewModel.Username, model.Password, False)
        TempData("LoginViewModel") = viewModel
        Return RedirectToLocal(viewModel.ReturnUrl)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then in my _Layout where I include the login partial:

```
@Code
    Dim model As LoginViewModel
    If TempData("LoginViewModel") IsNot Nothing Then
        model = TempData("LoginVieWModel")
    Else
        model = New LoginViewModel
    End If
    Html.RenderPartial("_LoginPartial", model)
End Code
```

Comment: TempData, makes sense. Wonder if ViewBag would make more sense as limited context variable.

Comment: I went with TempData because I'm using a redirect. I think I have to redirect because the action wouldn't know which view to return.